# Office.JS "This add-in is no longer available" error

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-addins, office-js, word-addins

Suddenly I started getting an error while loading an add-in:

> Error : "This add-in is no longer available: addin inserted during development are only available during debugging from visual studio. Please open your project in visual studio and re-run your application or deploy your add-in into a valid catalog and reinsert."

[image: Error Scree Shot]

When I used to run the project the addin used to load automatically. Now I am getting above error.I haven't made any changes to code and word.

Note: I have installed Fiddler today but after that add-in was working. I have reset my add-in but no use.

Comment: Are you able to visit the web site in the browser?

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but have you actually followed the advice from the error message and are actually debugging your add-in from within Visual Studio? Are you then still getting that error?

Comment: Dirk : This is what I was doing and getting the error. Running the visual studio in debug mode.

I am still getting the error.

Comment: Was it an existing document, or a brand new one every time?  Could it have been that the manifest ID had changed?

Comment: That points to you manifest, please make sure you configure your manifest correctly .

Comment: I thought that could be the issue. I replaced manifest from backup (source control) but it was showing the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this error. As a workaround I have created new project copied only home.html,home.js and other JS and CSS files and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is getting a bit old, I'd still like to bring some piece of information in case someone will have this problem later.

I had the exact same error message, but my `manifest.xml` was valid (no error with `npm run validate`, in a very recent project generated with yeoman), but I found out it was because I removed some icons resolutions I didn't use in the manifest.

@Gandalf is still right today, because Excel web is completely fine where the Windows desktop app complains. The best thing to avoid trouble is to keep a working template manifest, and then to compare when another causes an error.
[Here](https://github.com/Chi-Iroh/Excel-Add-In-Template) I created a repository with a documentation I'll update each time I'll face a new issue.
I don't care about auto-promotion, and I just linked it to help some people, as there's an obvious lack of relevant and up-to-date resources.

Comment: Similar scenario here: manifest validation passes and web version works, but not desktop. I also did comment unused icons. It looks like the issue is fixed when minimally providing these 3 resolutions : 16, 32, 80.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, it's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/icon?view=common-js-preview#image), I had a bad time trying to deal with this.
If you're interested, I'm working an add-in for 2 months now (from scratch) and I'll update my README soon. Also, if you have some experience with Office add-ins, feel free to open an issue on my repo to help people who may have the same issue later.

Comment: The real problem is that the validation has a lot of caveats, it seems it only checks the syntax. I guess I'll make a small script to wrap the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error recently in O365 Excel on Windows 10 but not in O365 Excel Web. In the end I solved it this way:

1. I ran `npm run validate`
2. This gave me a list of validation errors for the `manifest.xml`
3. I fixed the validation errors (In my case some String ids were too long)
4. I (re)started dev server `npm stop` `npm start`

So it seems like O365 Excel Web can cope with invalid manifest.xml to some extend whereas the app has a strikt validation of the file. I wish Office would output a meaningful error message in stead of a missleading "This add-in is no longer available". This did cost me roughly 6 hours to find out...

Answer (score 0):

I had this error not for studio code but with excel but it is kind of linked

I put the staging manifest that does not contain localhost url (this was the error return during validation)
and I replace then one by one with dev config even at the end I put back localhost and it works so there is a kind of cache somewhere but I did empty the cache.
between each step I click on the drop down of Excel insert/my add in arrow and the app name under developer add in